# Pivot query unique column error

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using the following query while getting error in oracle apex. Same query works in sql explorer:

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
             select PSROW as PSROW,
    PSCOLUMN as PSCOLUMN
FROM LOG_PS_STATUS
WHERE PSGROUP='PLANT'
            )
    SELECT *
    FROM   pivot_data
    PIVOT (
           MAX(NULL)        --<-- pivot_clause
          FOR PSCOLUMN--<-- pivot_for_clause        
        IN  (&PS_COLUMN.)   --<-- pivot_in_clause         

)
```

> The report query needs a unique key to identify each row. The supplied
>   key cannot be used for this query. Please edit the report attributes
>   to define a unique key column. ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or
>   sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want create interactive report ? if YES and if you no need detail view - you must "Link to Single Row View" set to NO when create IR.